# Count business class With same value

Tags: php, mysql, count

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
if (!$con){
die("Can not connect: " . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("mydb",$con);

        //Count all Total of Acc Class with same value Example Restaurant, Hotel
$query = "select acc_class,count(*) as total from mytable group by acc_class";
$result = mysql_query($query); 
$values = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
$num_total = $values['total']; 

while($record = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo '<br>';
echo "<label>" . $record['acc_class'] . "</label>";
echo "<label>" . $num_total . "</label>";
}   

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Guys please help me. I want to produce something like this. But I don,t know how.

```
Account Class   Total
-------------  -----------
Hotel            5
Restaurant       2
Club             3
Church           1
```

I want to have a page in which it will show total numbers of each account class. Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: Show your db structure

Comment: What does your current code give you? Also, you shouldn't use the deprecated `mysql_` functions anymore, move over to `mysqli_` or even `PDO`.

Comment: myquery return me with the account class name only but not the total numbers of each. hmm im new in mysql. and someone also told me about mysqli. i will try to learn that after my project. please help thanks!

Comment: this is my db structure : acc_class | varchar(50) | NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//you just need to put the name of the column in quert like COUNT(column_name)


    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
    if (!$con){
    die("Can not connect: " . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("mydb",$con);
    //data base connection ends here

    //you write a query to fire if you want by order the put "ORDER BY HERE"
    $query = "select acc_class,count(acc_class) as total from mytable group by acc_class";



    //here you fire a query to mysql  
    $result = mysql_query($query);    


    //now put the selected roe in loop and  again and again loop ask for more data to mysql
    while($record = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    **//here you select all the group in the table**

    echo '<br>';
    echo "<label>" . $record['acc_class'] . "</label>";
    echo "<label>" . $record['total'] . "</label>";


    }   

    //close connection to database
    mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: hi thank you i just found that my missing code was  $record['total'] instead of &num_total. thank you so much!

Comment: I upvoted this because i found this very helpful answer!

Answer (score 1):

Please dump $values:

var_dump($values);

I guess, the problem is it's either the data itself or the data-fetch (array, assoc).

Please format your SQL for better readability:

```
SELECT acc_class, COUNT(*) AS total FROM mytable GROUP BY acc_class;
```

The Count statement is correct: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html

Solution:

```
$query = "SELECT acc_class, COUNT(*) AS total FROM mytable GROUP BY acc_class";
$result = mysql_query($query); 

echo '<table border="1">';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo '<tr>';
   echo '<td>' . $row['acc_class'] . '</td>';
   echo '<td>' . $row['total'] . '</td>';
   echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Shouldn't this rather be a comment?